# Как сделать симуляцию разрезания ленточки в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Я в Unity новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать симуляцию разрезания ленточки в Unity. Нужно сделать так, что бы можно было обрезать ленточку ножницами.

Comment: Прежде чем резать ленточку, неким образом должна быть реализована сама ленточка.

Comment: Действительно) Все будет зависеть из чего у вас будет ленточка сделана. Если это будет статичный объект, то это одно, если объект будет представлять из себя ткань с физикой это другое). Для новичка вы не самую простую задачу себе поставили)

Comment: Как ткань. Просто, мне это очень важно реализовать) Ну, я не столько новичок, на самом деле. Основы знаю. Просто, хотелось объяснение по проще

Comment: проще всего, не углубляясь в сложности симуляции физики ткани, сделать это анимацией в блендере допустим